# Get an array as answer from HTTP request on iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, http, request

Is it possible to generate an array in a php on my server and, when requested through HTTP Request, send this array to the iPhone so I can work with that array values in the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you'd send it as JSON or XML and then use it however you need on the device

Comment: Is it better to send a JSON or a XML? Which one has the simplest parse methods?

Comment: I find it's easiest to parse JSON, I use SBJSON (http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) to parse JSON on an iPhone. It's incredibly easy to convert a PHP array to JSON as well, you just call json_encode($array) and be sure to send header types for application/json...

Answer (score 1):

You must send your array serialized into JSON for example:

```
<?php

    $data = array(
            'fullname' => 'Dan Jesus',
            'age' => 25
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

To capture this JSON object you sent in your javascript is simple, you can use JSON.parse(data) or if using jQuery can use $.parseJSON(data);